# Show that $T$ has an adjoint, and describe $T^*$ explicitly.

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, adjoint-operators

Let $V$ be an inner product space and $ \beta, \gamma$ fixed vectors in $V$. Show that
$T \alpha = (\alpha\mid\beta) \gamma$ defines a linear operator on $V$. Show that $T$ has an adjoint, and
describe $T^*$ explicitly.

**Attempt:**

The Linearity is easy. The problem is to find $T^*$.

$$ (Tv\mid u)=((v\mid \beta) \gamma\mid u)= (v\mid\beta)(\gamma\mid u)=(v\mid\overline{(\gamma\mid u)}\beta)$$.

Then $T ^ * u = \overline{( \gamma\mid u)} \beta = {(u\mid\gamma)}\beta$.

Is correct? I'm not sure you can do this $((v\mid\beta)\gamma\mid u)= (v\mid\beta)(\gamma\mid u)$. 
Any suggestion?

Comment: That's perfectly fine, as $(v \mid \beta)$ is a scalar like any other. The answer is correct.

Comment: @TheoBendit Thanks for the comment!